# How can we install mwc-menu

Tags: polymer-3.x

Some of the new material components released with Polymer 3.0, are not available from NPM. Is there any way to install them ? For example, how can we install mwc-menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available in npm.

> npm i @material/mwc-*

replace * with material item u r looking for

refer [this link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components)